# Eclipse: web project imported from version control not finding classes from server runtime

Tags: eclipse, svn, jakarta-ee, tomcat

I have a web project working in eclipse juno using tomcat 7 on one machine.  I exported this project to subversion, and imported it into a fresh workspace of eclipse juno on another machine which also has tomcat 7 installed.  To fix errors, I then set up the runtime "Apache Tomcat v7.0" on the second machine, and selected Projects/Clean/Clean all.

Now, my project has a list of libraries that includes "Apache Tomcat v7.0 [Apache Tomcat v7.0]", under which are listed all the jars in my tomcat installation, including servlet-api.jar, which eclipse is able to tell includes the package javax.servlet.http.  However, I have hundreds of compiler errors from my source of the form "The import javax.servlet.http cannot be resolved" etc.  Short of deleting and recreating the project (which might fix the second machine, but I worry that it will stop the project working on the original machine) what can I do to fix this?

*Correction:* the machines are running eclipse juno, not indigo as I previously stated.

Comment: is it a maven project or a "plain-eclipse" project?

Comment: Plain eclipse project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that this is a fairly simple and annoying but otherwise harmless eclipse bug -- it seems as though the list of libraries that constitutes a particular runtime is cached when the project is loaded, and doesn't get updated if the library list changes (e.g. because the runtime didn't exist when the project was imported, but was created afterwards).  Restarting eclipse causes it to reload the list, after which a project clean gets rid of the errors.

Answer (score 0):

If you did a refresh on the tree and a clean/build and the errors still exists, it must be the case, that they are not within the build path (check `.classpath` file).

So even though you may have checked it before, you should go there again and see if they are on the build path and maybe delete it and include them again.

Additionally, maybe [this article about the specific problem](http://tech.amikelive.com/node-269/eclipse-quick-tip-resolving-error-the-import-javaxservlet-cannot-be-resolved/) helps.

Comment: The classpath definitely included the correct libraries; they were even showing in the UI if I expanded the Java Resources/Libraries branch in the Project Explorer view.  I've added an answer below detailing what I found out...